# How do you set the width of a line in GraphicsMagick CLI?

Tags: graphicsmagick

I've tried using:

```
gm convert "source_image.jpg" -fill black -linewidth 50 -draw "line 100,100 100,200" output_image.jpg
```

But the line that GraphicsMagick draws is 1px wide. I've also tried using 'strokewidth' but the result is the same.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I'm using GraphicsMagick 1.3.16

Answer (score 0):

you could use -size, [-crop x{+-}{+-}{%}](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-crop)  or [geometry](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-geometry)

otherwise [format %w](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-format)   (width) may do it.